# How to inject service by name in symfony when using DependencyInjection

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have one service which is defined in services.yaml with different parameters:

```
user_uploader:
    class: App\Services\UploaderPath
    arguments:
        $basePath: "%users_directory%"

worker_uploader:
    class: App\Services\UploaderPath
    arguments:
        $basePath: "%workers_directory%"
```

When I'm injecting that service to another service everything is fine because I can inject it via name. 
The problem occurrs when I want to use DI and use for example `worker_uploader`

```
public function foo(UploaderPath $workerUploader) {
}
```

How in this case inject proper service?

Comment: I don't see the problem.  You would just define your foo service and inject the desired dependency.  If you want to use autowiring then you would be using class names for your services.  In this case, it would be easy enough to create a WorkerUploaderPath which extends from UploaderPath.

Comment: It's also possible that you may want to using the [binding capability](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-local-service-binding) of autowire.

Comment: I think @Cerad missed that you are trying to inject into a function. This is possible in Controllers that extend AbstractController but not possible in general services. In that case, you would need to inject your `$workerUploader` in the class constructor, set it as a class property and then use it like `$this->workerUploader->doFoo()`

Comment: @craigh I thought about that but only after posting my original comments.  It is possible that foo is actually a controller action method.  Was hoping to get a bit of feedback from the poster as it is not clear to me exactly what they are trying to do.

Comment: @craigh but then I have to register the controller in services.yaml and pass it as an argument eg: `@worker_uploader`?

Comment: @Cerad yes I could make some inheritance as you wrote, but I don't think that it's needed. Eventually I will make it.

Comment: I think, in that case, you could leverage bind. https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container.html#binding-arguments-by-name-or-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Symfony 3.4 or higher you can leverage bind in order to do that.

In service yaml

```
services:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            $userUploader: '@user_uploader'
            $workerUploader: '@worker_uploader'

    user_uploader:
        class: App\Services\UploaderPath
            arguments:
                $basePath: "%users_directory%"

    worker_uploader:
        class: App\Services\UploaderPath
            arguments:
                $basePath: "%workers_directory%"
```

Then let's say in a SomeController you can use it like so:

```
class SomeController extends AbstractController
{
    private $userUploader;
    private $workerUploader;

    public function __construct($userUploader, $workerUploader)
    {
        $this->userUploader = $userUploader;
        $this->workerUploader = $workerUploader;
    }
}
```

More details here https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container.html#binding-arguments-by-name-or-type

Comment: You made me the day. Still valid in SF6. I'm working with multiple DBAL connections and I did not want to manually attach the proper connection in the `services.yaml` for each of the many controllers. Instead of injecting `Connection $connection` I now use things like `Connection $connectionProductionIreland`  and `Connection $connectionProductionFrankfurt` and it just works. The controller demands what connection it wants and it gets injected!

Comment: Although as stated here https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-fundamentals/global-bind towards the end, the new `#[Autowire()]` attribute liberates us even from declaring the globals. In our case if the services are called `db.ireland` and `db.frankfurt` one can do: `public function __invoke( #[Autowire( service: 'db.ireland )] Connection $ireland, #[Autowire( service: 'db.frankfurt )] Connection $frankfurt )` and all is autocontained in the consuming class. No need to edit the services.yaml at all for routing the services.